# Critical points of $f(x)=|x^4 -16|+4x-2$, $x\geq -1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definition, absolute-value

As the title says, I found two critical points 1 and 2 with its derivatives, but I don't know how to find the last critical point $x=-1$, since $f(x)$ is defined when $x=-1$. I would really appreciate it if someone can explain this to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking *whether* $x=-1$ is a critical point, or are you asking *why* $x=-1$ is a critical point?

Comment: Hi Gonçalo, I would like to know both if possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: Best way to deal with absolute values is to consider the function as a piecewise function

Comment: Yes. I have done that, so I found two critical points. But I wonder why x=-1 is also a critical point.

Comment: For a continuous function on an interval, the extreme value theorem says that extrema can occur where the derivative is 0 or doesn't exist, or at the endpoints of the interval. -1 is the endpoint of the function's domain, so a maximum or minimum can occur there.

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition of "critical point", $x$ is a critical point of a function $f$ if the derivative of $f$ at $x$ is $0$ or undefined.

Thus, for the function

$$f(x)=\mid x^4−16 \mid +4x−2, x \geq -1$$

$x =-1$ is a critical point, because the derivative of $f$ at $x = -1$ is undefined. It is undefined, because: The derivative of $f$ at some $x = x_0$ exists iff the left derivative and right derivative both exist and are equal. And here clearly for $x = -1$, we only have right derivative but not left derivative, because $f$ is undefined  when $x<-1$.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: This is very clear and detailed. Thank you so much! Wish you have a good day.

Comment: You are welcome.